# A question on the cartesian product of two power sets for notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had a question with respect to the notation for the cartesian product of two power sets. For instance, suppose that $A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}$ and one were to determine the cartesian product of two sets for $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$, then would it be written as:

$\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset); (\emptyset,2); (1,\emptyset), (1,2)\}$

Or would one write it as the latter

$\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset); (\emptyset,\{2\}); (\{1\},\emptyset), (\{1\},\{2\})\}$ ?

I assume that it would be the latter case right ? Also, what exactly would the $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$ be in terms of notation (I do know that $\mathcal{P}(A \times B) = \{ \emptyset, A \times B\}$ but am a bit unsure about how to list the elements).

Advice would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct; the second one version is the correct product of power sets.

For the other question, you claim you know that $\mathcal P(A\times B)$ is a two-elements set whose elements are $\varnothing$ and $A\times B$, but then you say you don't know how to write down the elements... I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I mean that I saw the solutions to $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ but I'm actually not exactly sure why it is $\mathcal{P}(A)$ now after thinking carefully about it. Would you mind helping me to explain ? I figured that it may be something like $\mathcal{P}(A \times B) = \{\emptyset, \{(1,2)\} \}$ ?

Comment: The procedure for determining $\mathcal P(A\times B)$ is the same as the procedure for determining $\mathcal P(S)$ for any $S$. First, write out the elements of $A\times B$. Then, write down all collections of such elements. Then, put commas between them and braces on either end. Which step is giving you problems?

Comment: Oh, so to double check, it is exactly as I had written right ? $\mathcal{P}(A \times B) = \{\emptyset, \{(1,2)\} \}$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help and advice